# Why are the performances of these 2 queries so different?

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-execution-plan

I have a stored proc that searches for products (250,000 rows) using a full text index.

The stored proc takes a parameter that is the full text search condition. This parameter can be null, so I added a null check and the query suddenly started running orders of magnitude slower.

```
-- This is normally a parameter of my stored proc
DECLARE @Filter VARCHAR(100)
SET @Filter = 'FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL, robe)'

-- #1 - Runs < 1 sec
SELECT TOP 100 ID FROM dbo.Products
WHERE CONTAINS(Name, @Filter)

-- #2 - Runs in 18 secs
SELECT TOP 100 ID FROM dbo.Products
WHERE @Filter IS NULL OR CONTAINS(Name, @Filter)
```

Here are the execution plans:

Query #1
[image: Execution plant #1]

Query #2
[image: Execution plant #2]

I must admit that I am not very familiar with execution plans. The only obvious difference to me is that the joins are different. I would try adding a hint but having no join in my query I am not sure how to do that.

I also do not quite understand why the index called IX_SectionID is used, since it is an index that only contains the column SectionID and that column is not used anywhere.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`OR` can crush performance, so do it this way:

```
DECLARE @Filter VARCHAR(100)
SET @Filter = 'FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL, robe)'

IF @Filter IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP 100 ID FROM dbo.Products
    WHERE CONTAINS(Name, @Filter)
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP 100 ID FROM dbo.Products
END
```

Look at this article: [Dynamic Search Conditions in T-SQL by Erland Sommarskog](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html) and this question: [SQL Server 2008 - Conditional Query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2773268/65223]).

Comment: Nice article - adding `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` actually resolves the performance issue on the 2nd query (however another issue is that `CONTAINS()` raises an error when the parameter is NULL, but that's another problem).

Answer (score 3):

The first query plan looks straightforward:

1. a full text search to resolve `CONTAINS(Name, @Filter)`
2. an index scan to look up the other columns of the matched rows
3. combine the two using a hash join

The [concatenation operator](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/showplan-operator-of-the-week---concatenation/) forms a union of two recordsets.  So it looks like the second query is doing:

1. an index scan (later used to look up other columns)
2. a constant scan.  I assume it's treating your query as not parameterized, so the query plan doesn't have to work for any other value of `@Filter`.  If correct, the constant scan resolves `@Filter is not null`.
3. a full text search to resolve `CONTAINS(Name, @Filter)`
4. unions the result of 3 with the empty set from 2
5. loop joins the result of 1 and 4 to look up the other columns

A hash join trades memory for speed; if your system has enough memory, it's much faster than a loop join.  This can easily explan a 10-100x slowdown.

One fix is to use two distinct queries:

```
if @Filter is null
    SELECT TOP 100 ID FROM dbo.Products
else
    SELECT TOP 100 ID FROM dbo.Products WHERE CONTAINS(Name, @Filter)
```

Comment: Interesting - is there any way to force a hash join on the second query?

Comment: Yeah, you could rewrite it using `inner hash join`, but that would be rather complex.  It'd be better to use one of the solutions from the Sommarskog article.

Answer (score 1):

You've introduced an OR condition.
In most cases it is simply much faster to check explicitly for NULL and perform one query vs your method.

For instance try this:

```
IF @Filter IS NULL
 BEGIN
SELECT TOP 100 ID FROM dbo.Products
END
ELSE
BEGIN
SELECT TOP 100 ID FROM dbo.Products
WHERE @Filter CONTAINS(Name, @Filter)
END
```